# Set Cookies with AngularJS in ng-cordova for Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, cookies, ngcordova

I need to attach a cookie to my request header for my Python backend.

This is how I send it in through my normal app.

[image]

Now I'm doing an android version using cordova + angular + ng-cordova. But I'm having difficulties adding that cookie header.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Cookie = $scope.user;
```

This returns **Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"**

```
$cookies.putObject('labprot-user', $scope.user, {path: '/'});
```

This is ignored and doesn't send the cookie.

I'm using the following code:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('djangotoken');
$http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
$http.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Am I missing something, or is there a better way to send that information?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this using localstorage in cordova app:

// set item

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

// get item by key

```
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
```

// remove item

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

// clear local storage

```
 window.localStorage.clear();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My problem is not saving the cookie. I know I can use the localStorage. But I need to set it somehow so that it goes in the HTTP request header.